# How to prove this function is upper semicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

From Rudin's RCA:

> If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ is an *arbitrary* function, and 
>   $$\phi(x,\delta):=\sup\{|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\mid x_{1,2}\in(x-\delta,x)\cup(x,x+\delta)\},\,\phi(x):=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\phi(x,\delta).$$
>   Prove that $\phi$ is upper semicontinuous.

Somehow I can only show that $\phi(x,\delta)$ is *lower* semicontinuous for each $\delta>0$, not even remotely related to the result. How should I start?

Comment: @par no it's not continuous however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is immediate from the definition; you must have an inequality backwards or something.

You need to show that $$V_\alpha=\{x:\phi(x)<\alpha\}$$is open. Suppose $x\in V_\alpha$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ so that $$\beta=\phi(x,\delta)<\alpha.$$ Let $I=(x-\delta,x)\cup(x,x+\delta)$. So $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le\beta\quad(x_j\in I),$$which shows that $$\phi(y)\le\beta\quad(y\in I),$$so $I\subset V_\alpha$.

Comment: I don't understand why $\phi(y)\le \beta$. All I know is that in a small neighbourhood $x'\in J$ of $x$ (presumably smaller than $I$) we have $\phi(x',\delta)\ge |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|$. And I don't know any information about the opposite direction. In fact I doubt it's possible to upper bound $\phi(x')$.

Comment: @Vim Again, the fact that $\phi(y)\le\beta$ for $y\in I$ is immediate from the definitions. Suppose $y\in I$. There exists $\delta'>0$ so that $O=(y-\delta',y)\cup(y,y+\delta')\subset I$. Now $\phi(x,\delta)=\beta$ says that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\le\beta$ for all $x_1,x_2\in I$. Hence the same is true for all $x_1,x_2\in O$, which shows that $\phi(y,\delta')\le\beta$, and hence $\phi(y)\le\beta$.